# How do I fix "unknown" process utilizing 2.4GB of PageTable?

Tags: windows-7, memory, crash, memory-leaks

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YjhwKFJ.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cNZnrho.png]

Recently I noticed that my physical memory usage (according to the Windows resource monitor) was maxing out (only 4MB free) after a few hours even on an idle system after reboot. Doing some research on SuperUser I've learned how to track what may be causing it. The above screenshots show the research I've done. However, the process causing the problem is identified as "unknown". I'm stuck at this point and don't know how to proceed. What can I do to stop this ... memory leak (?) from occurring?

Also, I feel like there might be something else I'm missing because the 2.4GB that "unknown" process is taking doesn't seem like all the memory that's unaccounted for.

Comment: I asked a Microsoft PFE about this some time ago and you should contact the Microsoft support for help about this issue.

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's that complicated? :-/ I'd almost rather press the nuke button (reformat everything). Dealing with them sounds like a PITA, but I suppose I can try. Are you suggesting I call them or use their forums?

Comment: never ask tis in th forums. Only outsourced "employees" from China reply there. Contact the support directly: http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ln=en-us